# Xperia Z3 DRM Restore

Tags: backup, restore, partitions, sony-xperia-z, drm

I unlocked my Xperia Z3 without read risks (I'm in shame). Now I can't update phone with Sony Bridge, also read that I lost DRM licences.

So If some of my friends who has Z3 and still have bootlock, can take a TA partition backup for my device ? Can I restore this partition to my device ?

Comment: I'm not a Sony user, but that should be as easy as re-flashing the stock ROM. I wouldn't fiddle with partitions separately unless I knew exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't update phone cause of bootlock. I relocked it and updates are working... But keys are gone forever.